# Improve sql query function performance

Tags: php, sql, createprocess

I'm new to PHP, and was wondering if anyone could give an example of how to improve this code?

```
public function createContent($title, $content, $category_id){
        try {
            $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
            if(!$user_id){
                return(false);  
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO content (title, content, user_id, category_id) 
                    VALUES (:title, :content, :user_id, :category_id)";
            $query = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
            $execute_array = array(
                ':title' => $title,
                ':content' => $content,
                ':user_id' => $user_id,
                ':category_id' => $category_id
            );
            $query->execute($execute_array);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Have you singled out this method for a particular reason? I.e. do you already know that this method is slower/more resource hungry than it should be?

Comment: It looks fine to me.  If you're doing 100's of inserts it might be a good idea to "bulk" them up into 1 larger insert, but if it's ad-hoc, then your code looks good.

Comment: If you call this function several times, just call `_db->prepare` once, outside of it, because this is probably the only thing you might factor.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean with improve??
if your table only have "title, content, user_id, category" you can do it like:
"insert into content (:title, :content,:user_id, :category)";

but the best advice is to prepare statement, that will help you to avoid sql-injection